# Is it possible to implement a linked list using an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, implementation

I know that an ArrayList's size-1 can be the tail, while the ArrayList.get(0) can be the head, however, I'm uncertain whether the automatic resizing characteristic of ArrayList would make the LinkedList not be a linkedList.

Also, I am confused as what happens to the indexes of an ArrayList if it were to be implemented as a LinkedList.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  What do you mean by "implement a linked list with an array list?"

Comment: Certainly! What I mean by "implement a linked list with an array list is that" is it possible to create a linked list from scratch using an ArrayList?

Comment: You can copy an `ArrayList` into an `ArrayList`, but using an `ArrayList` as the data structure for a `LinkedList` is nonsensical.

Comment: I agree Louis! this is however an assignment to solidify one's grasping of how these data structures work. I'm looking more for possibility

Answer (score 0):

You must clear to yourself what are those structures:
(let's talk for simplicity about one sided not cycled list)

> Linked list is a linear collection of data elements, called nodes, each pointing to the next node.  It is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes which together represent a sequence.

So, one would create such structure by creating Nodes, who hold link to other Nodes of that type, and all this will be wrapped in some structure, speaking code:

Node class:

```
class Node<T>{
         private Node next;
         private T data;
    //getters etc.
}
```

LinkedList class:

```
class LinkedList<T>{
   private Node<T> head;
   // size, iterators, etc.
}
```

And and Array list is much different,

> Array list is a random access, variable-size list data structure that allows elements to be added or removed

This wikipedia quote is not very clear, so generally: it contains array inside it, something like:

ArrayList class:

```
class ArrayList<T>{
  private T[];
  //size, iterators, etc.
}
```

And this array is used to hold data/access data.

So it's not about heads, tails and indexes, it is about data structure itself, not even about Java's implementation, it has specific description and possibilities, so if you "implement Linked list using array list" it wouldn't be linked list(but frankly speaking, i cannot imagine how would one implement linked list with arraylist), exaggerating - it is almost the same thing as asking: "Is it possible to implement Integer with Thread"